# Hacer un GROUP BY a una consulta con un ORDER BY

Tags: mysql

Tengo una tabla llamada schedule con estas columnas:
[image: Tabla schedule]

Actualmente tengo estos datos:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Me gustaria poner ordenarlas primero por hora y después agruparlo por día pero no se como hacer el query para poder hacer las dos instrucciones.
He intentado esta instrucción pero solo me da como resultado uno de los tres datos que tengo en mi tabla.

```
    SELECT * FROM ( 
      SELECT *
      FROM schedule 
      ORDER BY startHour
    ) AS tmp_table GROUP BY day
```

EDIT:
Suponiendo que en los datos actuales existieran dos días

```
{"10-08-2017":[
    {"id":8,"day":"10-08-2017","startHour":"08:30","endHour":"13:30","title":"TALLER: Sistemas de Visi\u00f3n Artificial","speaker":" ","position":" "},
    {"id":9,"day":"10-08-2017","startHour":"09:30","endHour":"13:30","title":"TALLER: Adaptado Android a la Manufactura","speaker":" ","position":" "}
],
"11-08-2017":[
    {"id":10,"day":"11-08-2017","startHour":"08:30","endHour":"13:30","title":"TALLER: Rob\u00f3tica en la Manufaltura","speaker":" ","position":" "}
]}
```

Comment: Ana, no está claro lo que preguntas, si puedes agrega un ejemplo de los resultados que deseas obtener. Te explico: si agrupas por `day` no tiene sentido ordenar por `startHour`. Saludos

Comment: Ademas si agrupas por day, es logico que de un solo resultado, ya que las tres filas que mostraste tienen el mismo day. Cual es tu logica para usar un group by?

Comment: Claro, te da una sola fila porque precisamente el `GROUP BY` retorna **una fila por cada grupo**. Si dices el resultado que quieres obtener tendrás respuesta a tu pregunta, por el momento no queda claro lo que quieres. Si lo que quieres es ordenar por fecha y luego por hora aplicas ambas columnas en el ORDER BY: `SELECT *
      FROM schedule 
      ORDER BY day, startHour`

Comment: Me gustaria obtener por día los 3 elementos del día pero acomodados por hora. Y si existieran varios días tenerlos agrupados pra desplegar la información por día.

Comment: Creo que tienes un problema en la vista tambien? no puedes en una consulta tener los datos abiertos y agrupados. eso lo hacen las vistas, no las consultas. Aclara bien todas esas cosas, porque esta confuso realmente cual es tu problema. Pon ejemplos tambien de lo que quieres obtener.

Comment: Ya edite esperando que sea más claro, no se como ponerle formato al resultado.

Comment: Oye, pero eso es una salida de una variable en php? o sea tu problema esta en la vista? en ese resultado no estas mostrando nada diferente a la tabla original. Solo querias ordenarlos?

Comment: No, es que anteriormente esta página estaba en laravel y asi salian los datos de esa consulta.La razón por la que quiero ordenarlos de esa manera es porque en la vista los datos estna separados por tabs en días como si fuera una agenda.

Comment: He editado mi respuesta, la cual aporta, creo, una solución a tu problema. Cuando lo resuelvas, por favor ten en cuenta algunas observaciones que he hecho sobre el diseño de la tabla.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tu problema puede resolverse mediante una combinación de `GROUP BY` y `GROUP_CONCAT`, que te permitirá agrupar en una misma fila todas las fechas, y en una misma columna los otros datos diferentes de las otras columnas usando un separador.

Una consulta parecida a esta:

```
SELECT 
    day, 
    GROUP_CONCAT(startHour ORDER BY startHour SEPARATOR '|') horasInicio, 
    GROUP_CONCAT(endHour  ORDER BY endHour SEPARATOR '|') horasFin, 
    GROUP_CONCAT(title SEPARATOR '|') titulos 

FROM ordenar_20170904

GROUP BY day
ORDER BY day,startHour;
```

Como resultado, por cada fila tendrás tus datos agrupados y concatenados, por ejemplo para `startHour` tendrás tus horas separadas por `|` :

`08:30:00|08:30:00|09:30:00`

Luego, por programación, podrás hacer `split` sobre el separador para leer cada dato.

#### `Código:` [`Ver Demo`](http://rextester.com/OGQOFP1481)

```
CREATE TABLE  IF NOT EXISTS ordenar_20170904 (
                id SERIAL NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
                day VARCHAR(255),
                startHour TIME NOT NULL,
                endHour TIME NOT NULL,
                title VARCHAR(50)
    );



INSERT INTO ordenar_20170904 (day, startHour,endHour,title)
    VALUES 
    ('2017-08-10','08:30','13:30','Titulo 1'),
    ('2017-08-10','08:30','13:30','Titulo 2'),
    ('2017-08-10','09:30','13:30','Titulo 3'),
    ('2017-08-11','20:00','21:00','Titulo 4'),
    ('2017-08-11','19:30','21:00','Titulo 5');

SELECT 
    day, 
    GROUP_CONCAT(startHour ORDER BY startHour SEPARATOR '|') horasInicio, 
    GROUP_CONCAT(endHour  ORDER BY endHour SEPARATOR '|') horasFin, 
    GROUP_CONCAT(title SEPARATOR '|') titulos 

FROM ordenar_20170904

GROUP BY day
ORDER BY day,startHour;
```

#### `Resultado:`

```
day         horasInicio                 horasFin                    titulos
2017-08-10  08:30:00|08:30:00|09:30:00  13:30:00|13:30:00|13:30:00  Titulo 1|Titulo 2|Titulo 3
2017-08-11  19:30:00|20:00:00           21:00:00|21:00:00           Titulo 4|Titulo 5
```

---

**Nota:** He hecho SELECT de columnas por separado, pero se pueden concatenar varias columnas también.

---

#### Algunas observaciones sobre tu tabla

Me permito indicarte que hay un grave error de diseño en tu tabla. Todos tus campos de tipo fecha y/o hora están declarados como VARCHAR y además con un tamaño enorme, por ejemplo `day` está declarado `VARCHAR(255)`. Lo mejor es que esos campos sean del tipo `DATETIME`. Si en un futuro necesitas hacer cálculos con ese campo tendrás serios problemas, además de posibles errores que podrían cometer quienes manejen el programa a la hora de insertar los datos.

Lo mismo ocurre con `starHour` y con `endHour`. ¿`VARCHAR(255)` para almacenar una hora? OMG :) A lo sumo deberían ser declarados como `TIME`. Es más, fíjate que hasta te podrías ahorrar la columna `starHour` adosándola como hora en el campo `day`, pues si éste fuese DATETIME te permitiría guardar una fecha y una hora.

Espero te sirva.

Enlaces:

- [Documentación de `ORDER BY`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/order-by-optimization.html).
- [Documentación de `GROUP BY`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-handling.html).
- [Documentación de `GROUP_CONCAT`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat).

Comment: Fíjate que me parece que OP tiene otro problema.. esperemos a que aclare su duda. lo que le contestas esta perfecto, pero me parece que hasta que no aclare le vamos a tirar querys sin que sepamos a donde quiere llegar ;)

Comment: Su comentario fue editado luego de mi respuesta @gbianchi.

Comment: por eso te avisaba ;)

Comment: Gracias por la ayuda, ya edite mi pregunta esperando ser más clara.

Comment: @A.Cedano, revisa el JSON que agregó el OP, no parece ser que necesite agrupar sino más bien agregar registros nuevos por cada grupo. Saludos.

Comment: Gracias @PatricioMoracho No he interpretado que quiera agregar registros, sino agruparlos por fecha, al menos es eso lo que he entendido después de varios comentarios y ediciones de la pregunta. Saludos.

Comment: Muchas gracias me fue muy útil tu respuesta. Gracias por los comentarios de mi tabla lamentablemente eso no puedo cambiarlo por peticion de la persona que ocupa esos datos. Pero considero que tienes mucha razón en la forma que se guardan los datos.