# Erro al contar campos de tabla con SELECT condicionado

Tags: php, mysql

Saludos. Lo que intento hacer es lo siguiente. Necesito contar y mostrar cuantos estudiantes tienen como fecha de pago el día actual, para mostrarlo en una alerta que diga Hay 4 estudiantes que deben pagar hoy. Y ademas quiero mostrar en una lista los nombres de los estudiantes con fecha de pago de hoy. He hecho la consulta pero al parecer no me esta contando los registros. Las tablas las tengo relacionadas de la siguiente manera:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Las tablas están relacionadas como se puede apreciar. La consulta que he hecho es la siguiente:

```
 <?php 
 include '../lib/conexion.php';
 date_default_timezone_set('America/Caracas');
 setlocale(LC_ALL, "es_ES");
 $hoy = date('d-m-Y');

 $query = current($mysqli->query("SELECT COUNT(pagos_estudiantes.id), 
 students.names FROM students INNER JOIN inscritos ON 
 inscritos.id_student = students.id_students INNER JOIN pagos_estudiantes 
 ON pagos_estudiantes.id_inscripcion = inscritos.id WHERE 
 pagos_estudiantes.fecha_a_pagar = $hoy")->fetch_assoc());

  if($query){
    $alert = $query;
    $result = "Hay " . $query  . "que deben cancelar hoy";
   }

    echo $alert;
    echo $result;

  ?>
```

Esa es mi consulta pero como he dicho lo que me muestra es un 0 en el alerta, osea que no esta contando los registros. Lo que necesito es mostrar la cantidad de registros con fecha_a_pagar = hoy y los nombres de esos estudiantes

Comment: ¿Puedes por favor incluir de forma concreta los datos de entrada y los datos de salida que esperas obtener? En este caso, son 4 registros que esperas obtener, repitiendo en cada registro que el count es 4? Porque de una vez te puedo decir que algo no está bien con la consulta, porque estás haciendo select de `students.names` sin ponerlo en un `GROUP BY`. Eso usualmente te daría un error de una vez. Tristemente MySQL no da error, y solo luego te das cuenta de que los datos no están bien.

Comment: Saludos sstan, los datos que espero obtener es lo siguiente: que me diga cuantos estudiantes tienen en sus pagos pendientes un pago que tenga la fecha_a_pagar de hoy, por ejemplo: Hay 10 estudiantes que deben cancelar hoy. Ese 10 es el resultado que pretendo que me de la consulta, y el otro dato es que me liste los nombres de los estudiantes con fecha_a_pagar = $hoy.

Comment: Tanto tu código PHP como el diseño de tu BD son algo extraños Alejo. ¿Cuál es el sentido de esta relación `pagos_estudiantes.id_inscripcion = inscritos.id`, por qué no relacionas por el `id_estudiante`? ¿Por qué usas el tipo de datos `text` para campos del tipo `date`? Y en el PHP, ¿cuál es el sentido de usar `current` para obtener el valor... Es un código muy extraño y no creo que sea lo más eficaz (en caso de que funcione). A nivel de depuración, ¿has probado la consulta directamente en la base de datos para comprobar que arroja datos?

Comment: Cedano se que esa relación esta mal hecha, y lo peor es que ya no puedo editar las relaciones porque ese sistema ya tiene muchos registros y ya no puedo tocar esa parte. Ahora es que me doy cuenta que tuve que haber relacionado con el id del estudiante. El current con otras consultas lo he utilizado y me devuelve sin ningún problema los valores contados, pero lo he utilizado solo en consultas simples sin INNER JOIN

Comment: ¿Probaste la consulta fuera de PHP y arroja datos correctamente con ese criterio? Eso sería lo primero que habría que depurar. Luego, yo haría una consulta que me arroje una sola fila con dos columnas, una con el `COUNT` y otra con todos los estudiantes separados por algún carácter, usando `GROUP_CONCAT`, haciendo luego `explode` de esa columna para mostrar los estudiantes por separado. Sería algo parecido a [esta solución](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/99786/29967). En cuanto al PHP, haría un código normal... lo de `current` me parece muy extraño, de hecho, el Manual enseña otra forma.

Comment: Cedano he probado en mysql la consulta asi SELECT COUNT(`id`) FROM `pagos_estudiantes` WHERE fecha_a_pagar = 03-01-2018 y me arroja 0. Como si no tuviera registros con esa condición y en efecto tengo dos registros con esa condición.

Comment: **Revisa el contenido de tus datos**. Como te decía, el hecho de que tus campos son del tipo `text`, basta que haya allí un espacio en blanco... un carácter extraño, etc y ya los datos no son iguales. O basta que algún editor de la App haya escrito la fecha así `01-03-2018` o bien `2018-03-01`, o bien `2018-01-03`. Como comprenderás, usar otros tipos de campos para columnas que almacenarán fechas es, a la larga, muy problemático, sobre todo cuando hay varias personas encargadas de introducir datos en la App. Y si algún día tienes que hacer cálculos con esos datos tendrás otra dificultad más.

Comment: Eso lo valide para que siempre ingresen las fechas con el formato dd-mm-aaaa, tengo aqui la base de datos y revise todos esos datos y estan bien agregados. Me dijiste entonces que haga el COUNT solo y muestre el valor, y lo de la lista de estudiantes lo haga aparte?

Comment: Te dije que primero pruebes la consulta en mysql pero debes encerrar el criterio entre comillas simples: `SELECT COUNT(id) FROM pagos_estudiantes WHERE fecha_a_pagar = '03-01-2018'`, ya que es del tipo `TEXT`.

Comment: Luego, en el código final creas una sola consulta, algo así: `SELECT COUNT(pagos_estudiantes.id), 
     GROUP_CONCAT (students.names SEPARATOR '|') nombres FROM students INNER JOIN inscritos ON 
     inscritos.id_student = students.id_students INNER JOIN pagos_estudiantes 
     ON pagos_estudiantes.id_inscripcion = inscritos.id WHERE 
     pagos_estudiantes.fecha_a_pagar = '$hoy'" GROUP BY students.id_students` Tendrás una sola fila en resultado, más o menos así. Una primera columna con :`10` (por ej) y una segunda columna así: `Pedro|Juan|Andrés...`  podrás leer los nombres con `explode`.

Comment: Si cedano ya acababa de probar el criterio con comillas simples y si arroja los 2 datos. Hare lo que me dices con la consulta y paso por aqui

Comment: @Cedano me ha logrado funcionar. Ahora tengo dos problemas, no consigo la forma de imprimir el COUNT, he hecho esto $result[0] pero me arroja error, y el otro es que he hecho el explode("|", $row['names']); pero no me esta separando los nombres. Ya que los quiero mostrar es en una lista

Comment: Hay que mejorar tu código, y sanearlo, porque es vulnerable a la Inyección SQL. En cuanto a `explode`, te crea un array con todos los nombres que vengan, para mostrarlos, puedes entonces abrir un bucle `for` e imprimir cada elemento del array. Escribiré una respuesta.

Comment: Si ya ando mejorando lo del sql. Lo que no he podido saber es como imprimir el COUNT[pagos_estudiantes.id]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### La consulta

Puedes crear una consulta que te arroje una sola fila con dos columnas, en una tendrás el conteo y en otra todos los nombres de los estudiantes con un separador. Luego, harías `explode` de la segunda columna para presentar una lista de nombres.

La consulta sería más o menos así:

```
SELECT 
    COUNT(pagos_estudiantes.id) total, 
    GROUP_CONCAT (students.names SEPARATOR '|') nombres 
FROM students 
INNER JOIN inscritos ON inscritos.id_student = students.id_students 
INNER JOIN pagos_estudiantes ON pagos_estudiantes.id_inscripcion = inscritos.id 
WHERE pagos_estudiantes.fecha_a_pagar = ? 
GROUP BY students.id_students
```

### El código PHP

Como ya dije en comentarios, tu código PHP es *extraño*, y no es la forma habitual que enseña el Manual (ni la práctica común) para leer nuestros resultados.

También, tu consulta hay que sanearla, pues es vulnerable a la Inyección SQL. Para resolver esa vulnerabilidad, modificaremos considerablemente tu código, aplicando los métodos existentes para ello. O sea, cambiar el valor `$hoy` que antes pasabas directamente en la instrucción SQL, por un marcador de posición `?`, y el valor en sí pasarlo aparte, mediante el método `bind_param`.

Esta es la propuesta:

```
<?php 
    include '../lib/conexion.php';
    date_default_timezone_set('America/Caracas');
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "es_ES");
    $hoy = date('d-m-Y');

    /*El signo ? usado es para preparar la consulta*/
    $query= 
         "SELECT 
            COUNT(pagos_estudiantes.id) total, 
            GROUP_CONCAT (students.names SEPARATOR '|') nombres 
        FROM students 
        INNER JOIN inscritos ON inscritos.id_student = students.id_students 
        INNER JOIN pagos_estudiantes ON pagos_estudiantes.id_inscripcion = inscritos.id 
        WHERE pagos_estudiantes.fecha_a_pagar = ? 
        GROUP BY students.id_students";

    /*Preparamos y pasamos los valores aparte para evitar la inyección de código*/      
    $stmt = prepare($query);
    $stmt->bind_param("s", $hoy); //Aquí se envía el valor, separado de la consulta en sí
    $stmt->bind_result($total, $nombres);
    $stmt->store_result();

    /*Verificamos si hubo resultados*/
    if ($stmt->num_rows > 0){

        while ($stmt->fetch()) {
            $intTotal=$total;
            $arrNombres=explode("|",$nombres);
        }

        echo "Hay " . $intTotal  . " que deben cancelar hoy";

        /*Mostramos una lista con los nombres*/
        echo "<ul>";
        foreach ($arrNombres as $nombre){
            echo "<li>".$nombre."</li>";
        }
        echo "</ul>";

    }else{
        echo "No se encontraron datos";    
    }
    /*Cerrar recursos*/
    $stmt->free_result();
    $stmt->close();
?>
```

Comment: Excelente respuesta +1, siempre he tenido un duda al usar esto `$hoy = date('d-m-Y');` la fecha que imprimirá `PHP` siempre va hacer la de nuestro ordenador, o ese uso siempre detectara la fecha actual, a pesar de tener en mi ordenador una fecha mal ejemplo `03/02/2015` o mostrara a pesar de ello la fecha verdadera `03/01/2018`

Comment: Saludos. Muestra la fecha del servidor!

Comment: @IniDesing.com esa podría ser una pregunta interesante. `date` imprimiría la fecha actual, pero no necesariamente del ordenador, sino del equipo que haga de servidor, o sea, el equipo donde está el archivo PHP que ejecute `date`. Por ejemplo, si abres una página web que imprima el valor de `date` te imprimirá la fecha del servidor, no la de tu ordenador, ya que PHP corre del lado del servidor. O bien otra fecha si indicas explícitamente una Zona Horaria concreta. En cambio, si es con Javascript, entonces sí te mostrará la fecha de tu ordenador, porque se ejecuta del lado del cliente.

Comment: Mucho mejor respondida por ti Cedano. Por cierto he probado tu respuesta y funciona sin problemas. Y si ya he empezado a usar pdo para mi codigo. Muchas gracias de nuevo

Comment: @A.Cedano Excelente se debería aclarar este tema en una pregunta, quizás dando refuerzos en fallo de fechas porque al fin de cuentas nuestros proyectos son subidos desde un servidor donde no tenemos acceso quizás a esa información, no se quizas se podría realizar algo avanzado sobre ese tema para evitar futuras burlas en el sistema, saludos :)

Answer (score 0):

Ya que necesitas mostrar los nombres y otros datos, no utilices el `count` haz la consulta y luego obtienes el número de filas con `num_rows`

La consulta puede ser algo así, ya la ajustas a tus necesidades.

```
SELECT *
FROM students 
INNER JOIN inscritos 
ON inscritos.id_student = students.id_students 
INNER JOIN pagos_estudiantes 
ON pagos_estudiantes.id_inscripcion = inscritos.id 
WHERE 
pagos_estudiantes.fecha_a_pagar = $hoy
```

Luego

```
$resultado = $mysqli->query('CONSULTA');

echo 'Número de registros: '.$resultado->num_rows;

while ($fila = $resultado->fetch_assoc()) {
    echo $fila["names"].', '.$fila["fecha_a_pagar"];
 }
```

Cómo te han comentado es una pésima idea utilizar `text` para campos de fechas.