# Tabla HTML para consulta de 2 tablas en PHP

Tags: php, mysql

Tengo dos tablas (ambas relacionadas por su ID):

```
Socios:             Socios_carga
------------        --------------
ID                  ID
Nombre              Nombre
RUT                 RUT
```

Luego con `INNER JOIN` genero la consulta de estas tablas relacionadas

```
$query="SELECT socios.nombre, socios_carga.nombre_carga, socios_carga.rut_carga FROM socios INNER JOIN socios_carga on socios.id=socios_carga.id_carga ORDER BY socios.nombre"; 

$resource = $conn->query($query); 
$total = $resource->num_rows;
```

y me muestra algo así:

> Socio1 Carga1
>   Socio1 Carga2
>   Socio1 Carga3
>   Socio2 Carga1
>   Socio2 Carga2

Y lo que yo necesito es que me muestre en una tabla HTML lo siguiente:

```
Socio1
 Carga1 
 Carga2  
 Carga3

Socio2
 Carga1   
 Carga2
```

No se si esto se logra agregando algo a la consulta o bien agregando algún código al PHP.

Código HTML y PHP que muestra la consulta:

```
<table id="example" class="display" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Titular</th>
            <th>Nombre</th>
            <th>Rut</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <?php while ($row = $resource->fetch_assoc()){?>
            <td><?php echo $row[nombre]?></td>
            <tr>
            <td><?php echo $row[nombre_carga]?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row[rut_carga]?></td>

            </tr>

        </tr>
      <?}?>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

=============================================================
Tabla 'socios_carga'
Como podrán ver el ID=9 del socio no tiene carga y el ID=11 tiene solo 2 cargas
[image]

Y su resultado en HTML es el siguiente:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Podrias publicar el query y una descripción de los esquemas de las tablas?

Comment: $query="SELECT socios.nombre, socios_carga.nombre_carga, socios_carga.rut_carga FROM socios INNER JOIN socios_carga on socios.id=socios_carga.id_carga ORDER BY socios.nombre";
$resource = $conn->query($query); 
$total = $resource->num_rows;

Comment: Por favor edita la pregunta, agrega el query ahí, y formatealo como código para que sea fácil leerlo.

Comment: Editada la Pregunta con la consulta! Gracias!

Comment: Ese formato de salida lo generas vos en un loop que lee cada registro del resultado de ejecutar el query,  armando en el php el html de salida que querés. Podría ser una tabla o columnas de bootstrap.

Comment: Esto se "Formatea" en el PHP, debes tener una variable de texto (inicialmente vacía), en el bucle de lectura del "DataSet", comparar esta variable con la columna de `Socio`, si son distintas, "creas el cabezal" y suplantas la variable de texto por la del dato de la columna de socio, después imprimes la carga indistintamente. En el siguiente ciclo del bucle, la variable será igual a la del dato socio, por lo cual no se escribirá el cabezal. Saludos.

Comment: Muchas Gracias @RicardoGalain
Agregue mi codigo de HTML y PHP para ver si me puedes orientar un poco más con tu solución. Muchisimas gracias

Comment: Andrés, para este tipo de casos yo suelo usar una combinación de `GROUP_CONCAT` y `GROUP BY`. Esto traerá los resultados así: `Socio1` en una columna y en otra columna: `Carga1|Carga2|Carga3`  y para cada socio algo parecido. Luego por programación haces `explode` de las cargas y las muestras como quieras. [Aquí puedes ver un ejemplo de lo que digo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/99786/29967).

Comment: @A.Cedano Sorry, creo que mi pregunta sobre como quiero que me muestre el resultado estaba mal explicado, ahora lo arregle!

Comment: Lo cierto es que la solucion de @A.Cedano es mas correcta que la mia, solo que depende del funcionamiento de esa funcion (que francamente nunca use. [Referencia aqui](https://www.w3resource.com/mysql/aggregate-functions-and-grouping/aggregate-functions-and-grouping-group_concat.php), el resultado de eso con un [explode](http://php.net/manual/es/function.explode.php) e [implode](http://php.net/manual/es/function.implode.php) y lo tenes hecho con algo tan sensillo como `<td><?php echo $row[nombre]?></td><td><?php implode('</td><td>', explode(",", $row["ColumnaDelGroupConcat"])) ?></td>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cito:

> Esto se "Formatea" en el PHP, debes tener una variable de texto (inicialmente vacía), en el bucle de lectura del "DataSet", comparar esta variable con la columna de Socio, si son distintas, "creas el cabezal" y suplantas la variable de texto por la del dato de la columna de socio, después imprimes la carga indistintamente. En el siguiente ciclo del bucle, la variable será igual a la del dato socio, por lo cual no se escribirá el cabezal.

El codigo seria asi:

```
<table id="example" class="display" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
    <thead>
        <tr>
        <th>Titular</th>
             <th>Nombre</th>
             <th>Rut</th>
         </tr>
     </thead>
     <tbody>
         <tr>
         </tr>

             <?php $socio = ""; while ($row = $resource->fetch_assoc()){?>
             <?php if ($socio <> $row['nombre']){ $socio = $row['nombre']; echo '<tr><td>' . $row['nombre'] . '</td><td></td><td></td></tr>'} ?>
        <tr>
             <td></td>
             <td><?php echo $row['nombre_carga']?></td>
             <td><?php echo $row['rut_carga']?></td>
        </tr>
              <?php } ?>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Nótese la nueva variable `$socio`, siendo esta un string definido fuera del bucle generado por el `while`. Inicialmente de valor `""`, y posteriormente (cada vez que el usuario "cambie", la comparación con ésta "detectará" el cambio, y se sobrescribirá, para "esperar" el próximo cambio.

**Paralelamente,** 
otra solucion seria, basandonos en la funcion [GROUP_CONCAT](https://www.w3resource.com/mysql/aggregate-functions-and-grouping/aggregate-functions-and-grouping-group_concat.php) sugerida por A. Cedano. Podriamos dejar el sql de la siguiente manera:

```
SELECT socios.nombre, group_concat(concat('<td></td><td>', socios_carga.nombre_carga, '</td><td>', socios_carga.rut_carga , '</td>') separator '</tr><tr>') as cargas
FROM socios 
INNER JOIN socios_carga 
on socios.id=socios_carga.id_carga 
GROUP BY socios.nombre
ORDER BY socios.nombre
```

Yo no recomiendo dar formatos de salida desde la consulta SQL, pero se me hizo demasiado fácil.

Y el código seria el siguiente:

```
<table id="example" class="display" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
    <thead>
        <tr>
        <th>Titular</th>
             <th>Nombre</th>
             <th>Rut</th>
         </tr>
     </thead>
     <tbody>
         <tr>
         </tr>

             <?php while ($row = $resource->fetch_assoc()){?>
        <tr>
             <td><?php echo $row['nombre'] ?> </td><td></td><td></td>
        </tr> 
        <tr>
             <?php echo $row['cargas']?>
        </tr>
              <?php } ?>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

PD: No estoy seguro si es necesario, pero como verás declaro las celdas vacías de la tabla.

Comment: Estimado Ricardo, tu magistral solución a sido de gran ayuda y a solucionado mi problema... Muchas pero muchas gracias a ti y a todos los aportes!! 
PD: Solo faltaría agregar un ; dentro del Loop al final de </td>

Comment: @AndrésJara, me sobrestimas, la mejor solución la planteó sin dudas A. Cedano. La mía (originalmente) es la mas lineal y genérica para esos casos. Respecto a la falta de `;` diré que se me hace raro abrir y cerrar la etiqueta de PHP, yo suelo concatenar los HTML directo en los `echo`, de ahí el mareo.

Comment: Paralelamente, una corrección, si bien el compilador no lo toma como un error critico, en `$row[nombre_carga]` es incorrecto usar `nombre_carga` sin comillas, esto haria al compilador intentar interpretarla como una constante y dado que es inexistente dicha constante, asume que es un valor y no la constante. Esto despliega errores si los tenes habilitados.

Comment: Muchas gracias @RicardoGalain por la corrección... aprovechando la buena voluntad de ayudar... ¿Cómo será posible decirle <?php echo $row['cargas']?> que no se muestre si no tiene datos? ya que al momento de listar los datos, me muestra igualmente la fila en blanco, generando espacio no deseado en la tabla! Se entiende?

Comment: No hay de que, para eso estamos. Te diré que me resulta extraño que exista una linea sin datos en 'cargas', porque significa que.. pese a haber un `ON socios.id=socios_carga.id_carga` existen `socios_carga.nombre_carga=''`  y `socios_carga.rut_carga=''`. por lo que.. diria que algo no esta bien en la estructura de datos... paralelamente una solución "tonta" seria añadir `HAVING NOT (group_concat(socios_carga.nombre_carga) = '' AND group_concat(socios_carga.rut_carga) = '')` al sql.

Comment: Agregue unas fotografías a la misma pregunta donde muestro que el socio titular puede agregar hasta 3 cargas, así como también, puede que no tenga cargas y este "Forever Alone". no obstante en la impresión del HTML me muestra las filas sin datos!

Comment: Bueno por lo que veo puede "agregar hasta 3 cargas" es un decir, porque la realidad es que ya las tiene realmente agregadas (relacionadas por `socios.id=socios_carga.id_carga`). La pregunta es.. que datos tienen?, son `Null` o son `''` (string vacio). Por otro lado, al final que resolucion tomaste?, la "mia" o modificaste el SQL con "la idea" de A. Cedano (que te pasé yo). Si es la original, pone el `where not ...` de esos valores, si es la "modificada por mi", metes los resultados de una función agregada como el group_concat() de esos campos en el `having not ..`.