# Consulta Mysqli ,Agrupar y mostar resultados

Tags: php, mysqli

necesito mostrar resultados agrupados por precio( desde , hasta )

Valores de mi DB:

```
articulo |   fecha   | precio

pelota   |2018-11-10 |  10 

pelota   |2018-11-11 |  10

pelota   |2018-11-12 |  11

pelota   |2018-11-13 |  11

pelota   |2018-11-14 |  11

raqueta  |2018-11-10 |  100

raqueta  |2018-11-11 |  100

raqueta  |2018-11-12 |  110

raqueta  |2018-11-13 |  110

raqueta  |2018-11-14 |  110
```

El resultado que necesito seria mostrar asi:

**Precio de lista :**

```
pelota : desde 2018-11-10 al 2018-11-11 $ 10

pelota : desde 2018-12-10 al 2018-11-14 $ 11

raqueta: desde 2018-11-10 al 2018-11-11 $ 100

raqueta: desde 2018-12-10 al 2018-11-14 $ 110
```

Lo unico que se me ocurre es buscar fecha minima y maxima y hacer un bucle for desde fecha minima hasta fecha maxima incrementando 1 dia.
toma valor inicial del precio guardo en array y comparo en posicion -1 a la actual.

Comment: Esto lo puedes lograr fácilmente usando `GROUP_CONCAT` en la consulta SQL.

Comment: Gracias , voy a leer la documentacion!

Comment: [Aquí tienes un ejemplo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/82380/29967) muy parecido a lo que quieres. Agrupa los valores de la columna `reciever` y los separa con un `|`. Dentro del grupo puedes ordenar también por cualquier columna o por varias columnas. [Este es un ejemplo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/99786/29967) con orden interno en las columnas que se agrupan. [Aquí hay otro ejemplo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/158848/29967), donde explico también cómo trabajar los resultados por programación en PHP.