# Mostrar select de acuerdo al subnivel de producto (MYSQL PHP)

Tags: php, mysql

Estoy creando un punto de venta y necesito que cuando el producto tenga un subnivel me muestre un select con los lotes y cuando tenga 2 subnivel me muestre un select con un optgroup segun los lotes del producto.

Les explico mi estructura literal:

> **subnivel = 0 :** el producto solo tiene lotes por ejemplo mascarillas KN95 tiene 100 unidades
>
> **subnivel = 1 :** el producto tiene sublotes por ejemplo shampoo agu > Manzanilla (option 1), Menta (option 2), Fresa (option 3).
>
> **subnivel = 2 :** el producto tiene sublotes dentro de sublotes por ejemplo:
> **Pantalon Pioner >** Talla M > *Color Azul, Color Blanco, Color Verde*; Talla S > *Color gris, Color amarillo, Color Verde*

Ahora les muestro la estructural en base de datos:

**PRODUCTOS:**
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**LOTES**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Como deseo que se muestre el sistema:**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Codigo Mysql que tengo de momento:**

```
$con_productos = "SELECT PROLOT.*,PRO.producto,PRO.tipo
FROM productos_lotes PROLOT
LEFT JOIN productos PRO ON PRO.id_producto = PROLOT.id_producto
GROUP BY PROLOT.id_producto 
ORDER BY PRO.producto ASC
";
$exe_productos = $bd->query($con_productos);
```

Este codigo me lista los lotes agrupados por productos y lo que estoy haciendo es que si producto > tipo es igual a 1 o 2 entonces quiere decir que va a tener sub niveles y pongo un select, la cosa es como meterle los subniveles a esos select o agrupar los subniveles dentro de subniveles.

Quiero evitar hacer muchas consultas ya que promedio que habran algo de 1000 productos mostrandose en una sola pagina.

Comment: `GROUP_CONCAT()` combinado con `GROUP BY` es muy útil para estos casos. [Mira este ejemplo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/99786/29967), las fechas vienen en una sola columna, y cada valor viene agrupado y concatenado por un separador, que en este caso es `|`, luego, podrías usar `explode` para obtener cada valor individual. Con `GROUP_CONCAT` y `CONCAT` podrías también construir una estructura tipo JSON y leerla de una forma más intuitiva, recorriendo como si fuera un array, etc.

Comment: ¿Qué vas a usar para el estilo? ¿Bootstrap, material, ...?

Comment: @Sal ninguno, mi propia hoja de estilo

Comment: Para lo que dices yo haria que cada 'sublote' sea una tabla, y cada uno de estos relacionado entre si.

Answer (score -1):

Como dijo @A. Cedano una de las soluciones es utilizar el `GROUP_CONCAT()` combinando con `GROUP BY` te dejo una muestra de como lo puedes hacer

**Código MYSQL en tu caso**

```
SELECT PRO.producto, GROUP_CONCAT(PROLOT.json) AS lotes  FROM producto PRO
LEFT JOIN (SELECT id_producto, CONCAT(nivel1,':"',GROUP_CONCAT(nivel2 SEPARATOR '*'),'"') AS json
FROM lote GROUP BY id_producto,nivel1) PROLOT ON PROLOT.id_producto=PRO.id_producto GROUP BY PRO.id_producto
```

esta sentencia sql realiza una subconsulta a la tabla lote para crear una tabla en donde crearemos un json dinámico a partir de los lotes del producto.

**PHP**

```
$exe_productos = $bd->query($con_productos);
$json=[];
foreach($exe_productos as $key=>$val){
    $json[$key]=$val["producto"].":{".$val["lotes"]."}";
}
echo '<script type="text/javascript">var productos={'.implode(",", $json).'};</script>';
```

con esto ya tendrías un json bien organizado para obtener los lotes y sublotes de los productos desde una variable global en javascript

si lo hicieras con ajax solo tendrias que enviar el id_producto y la sentencia sql quedaria de esta forma

**Código MYSQL para ajax**

```
SELECT PRO.producto, PROLOT.nivel1, GROUP_CONCAT(PROLOT.nivel2) FROM producto PRO LEFT JOIN lote PROLOT
ON PROLOT.id_producto=PRO.id_producto GROUP BY PROLOT.nivel1 WHERE PRO.id_producto=103
```

Comment: queria manejarlo solo con php y mysql, que una consulta me genere eso, tu respuesta es buena pero es demaciado consumo en ram